# iPhone > Set position of an control

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to find the easiest way to set a position of an control.

So this works to set the object +100px:

```
[panel setFrame:CGRectMake(
   panel.frame.origin.x, panel.frame.origin.y + 100,
   panel.bounds.size.width, panel.bounds.size.height)
];
```

But of course this is painful.

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
panel.frame.origin.y += 100; // Compiler error

[panel setPosY:100];  // has no effect of my control
```

Isn't there a easy way to set the position?

Answer (score 3):

you can always use the center property of an object:

`panel.center = CGPointMake(panel.center.x, panel.center.y + 100);`

That's probably the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Oh, thanks to you both, 
I was confused about the name "center"
But why isn't this directly way allowed in Obj-C?
panel.center.y += 100;

Comment: This is the trick with properties; panel.center is actually a method call that returns a CGRect structure; it's not giving you direct access to the object's frame instance variable. Therefore, when you modify that struct, the original structure (inside the object's memory space) is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way I know of is:

```
panel.frame = CGRectOffset(panel.frame, 0.0f, 100.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work and is slightly shorter than your initial code:

```
CGRect frame = panel.frame;
frame.origin.y += 100;
panel.frame = frame;
```

Still not very pretty, though.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to move it out of the way *and* decrease the length (so it ends at the same place) you may want to try the following (thanks racha for the idea)

```
    // Make space at start of label
    CGRect frame = mainLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 100;
    frame.size.width -= 100;
    mainLabel.frame = frame;
```